# Anyone knows if vibe.d supports HTTP Byte-Range while serve static files?

Tags: http, web, server, d, vibed

I was looking in the source code of `vibe-d-0.7.28` but `fileserver.d` doesn't show any light about this. Actually, the `sendFileImpl()` function is the main implementation for that job and doesn't have any reference to byte-range header.

Do you know if that is supported or how works?

Comment: Do you mean the HTTP range requests (described in RGC 7233)? "Byte Range" in D can also mean an input/output ranges of `byte`/`ubyte`, which are a specific data structure.

Comment: I mean HTTP Byte Range (RFC 7233). sorry for be ambiguous. I will change the question

Comment: You should definitely submit an enhancement request (aka issue) at the [vibe.d](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d) repo ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since [#1634](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/pull/1634) this is possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env dub
/+ dub.sdl:
name "mini_vibed"
dependency "vibe-d" version="~>0.8.0-beta.4"
versions "VibeDefaultMain"
+/

import vibe.d;

shared static this()
{
    auto settings = new HTTPServerSettings;
    settings.port = 8080;

    auto router = new URLRouter;
    router.get("/full_file", (scope req, scope res) {
        auto inStream = openFile(__FILE_FULL_PATH__);
        res.bodyWriter.write(inStream);
    });
    router.get("/partial_file", serveStaticFile(__FILE_FULL_PATH__));
    router.get("*", (scope req, scope res) {
        res.writeBody("Please try /full_file or /partial_file");
    });

    listenHTTP(settings, router);
}
```

Either `chmod +x` the file or run it with `dub --single`.
You can use `curl` to test it:

```
curl --header "Range: bytes=0-200" localhost:8080/full_file
curl --header "Range: bytes=0-200" localhost:8080/partial_file
```